# Support for Windows audio drivers on a Chromebook

Tags: audio, drivers

I am running Windows on a Levono Ideapad 3 Chromebook and I cant find an audio driver without paying for it. Does anybody know how I can find a driver?

Specs:

- Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz
- 4.00 GB
- Windows 10 Pro (22h2)

Ven ID: `\VEN_8086&DEV_3198&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_06\3&b1bfb68&0&70`

Comment: I wouldn't pay for something like that. People offering this are likely to be scammers, it seems to me. But, I'm also not very involved in the communities getting Windows to run on Chromebooks, so my advice my not be correct.

Comment: Second, does Windows identify any sort of audio devices in Device Manager? If so, what are the hardware identifiers for these? This is likely to be the only way to determine WHICH device's drivers you need to get for this.

Comment: I looked up several of these machines (close as I could find) and no Windows drivers for the Chromebooks.  Windows will try to find drivers from the Microsoft Catalog if such drivers exist.

Comment: @music2myear, No speakers are showing up inside of my device manager.

Comment: As expected if there are no proper drivers installed. What you should be looking for is unidentified devices (with an yeallow "?"), check their properties and post here the VID (Vendor ID) & PID (Product ID) by [edit]ing your question. With that information someone *might* find something useful; without it the question can't be answered. There are no other options.

Comment: 8086:3198 Is a HDMI Audio device that I seriously doubt not having support in Windows 10 even in a chromebook. Are you really looking for HDMI audio drivers? WHY. doesn't it work??

Comment: @ChanganAuto , I found the HDMI audio driver and installed it no problem. But still, is there any way to get sound playing out of the laptop's speakers?

Comment: That is exactly the VID&PID you should've posted. What was the point of adding a device that works?

Comment: SURELY a much better option is Ubuntu. That one you already know works fine: https://askubuntu.com/a/1486279/1210606 . If you want a Windows laptop BUY a Windows laptop, don't install pirated Windows in chromebooks.